# C program, stuck in a for loop

Tags: for-loop

I'm a newbie to C. I'm in an infinite loop and cant see to figure out why. This is what I have tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int SEED, TIMES_ROLL,COUNT,DICE1, DICE2;

    //Ask user for seed value
    printf("Type in a number for the seed value?\n");
    scanf("%d", &SEED);

    srand(SEED);

    //Ask user how many times to roll the 2 dice
    printf("How many times would you like to roll the dice?\n");
    scanf("%d", &TIMES_ROLL);

    for (COUNT = 1; COUNT > TIMES_ROLL; COUNT + 1)
    {
            DICE1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            DICE2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            printf("%d and %d rolled\n", DICE1,DICE2);
    }
```

Comment: what value did you input for TIMES_ROLL? It is easy quite easy if you fully understand the concepts. Try to solve it first, deduce the problem like what causing my loop to ionfinite? is my loop condition valid?

Comment: You need to use less-than operator `COUNT < TIMES_ROLL;`

Comment: COUNT ++ and not COUNT +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not increment the COUNT and your sign is wrong:

```
 for (COUNT = 1; COUNT > TIMES_ROLL; COUNT + 1)
```

It should be

```
 for (COUNT = 1; COUNT <= TIMES_ROLL; ++COUNT)
```

Comment: @infixed: They were right. Our answers were just partially correct. After seeing the first mistake with increment I did not notice that the sign was wrong too. Thus, the punishment. On the other hand, those downvoters are too scared to answer themself because they afraid that another guy like them downvote their answer, so they are writing their answers in comments.

Comment: Yeah, the question was "Cant yall help me out here?", and fixing one mistake is help.  Just so you know,  as of this moment none of your score is due to a downvoter reversing themselves.

Comment: @infixed: I think they just can't reverse their downvote. Stackoverflow does not allow it (at least after some point). And that is wrong, because sometimes people downvoting because they don't know that you are in fact correct, and they are wrong. I was downvoted for such case in the past.

Comment: Stackoverflow does allow you to up vote something you previously down voted.  The person so voted actually comes out ahead.   If one couldn't do this there is no motive to improve one's answers.  It's done to get questioners to improve their questions quite frequently. At least in theory.  I see many down votes commented "you question is unclear, add more" but never seem to be undone, even when the question is edited to add the stuff supposedly missing

Answer (score -1):

in `for (COUNT = 1; COUNT > TIMES_ROLL; COUNT + 1)`, the final bit just becomes a value of `COUNT+1`.

You want to assign that new value into COUNT itself.

use

```
COUNT = COUNT+1
```

or as is more commonly done

```
++COUNT
```

You also have the comparsion inverted.  Use less-or-equal than i.e. `COUNT <= TIMES_ROLL` as the middle expression in the `for` statement

In common usage, counting is often done zero based.  So even more conventionally

```
for (COUNT = 0; COUNT < TIMES_ROLL; ++COUNT)
```

Comment: nice to see down votes without explanation on simple usage of a `for` statement